# Pressing "Ask Question" while not logged in does not take me to the log in page

Tags: support, asking-questions

I notice that when I am not logged into Workplace and I want to ask a question, clicking on "Ask Question" takes me to the page to create the question rather than the sign in page. This is in contrast to other SE sites which I've used which do the opposite (prompt me to sign in before taking me to that page). Is this a bug? Why does Workplace differ in this regard?

Comment: When you say "other sites", you mean other SE sites behave differently in this regard?  Or do you mean other sites on the Internet?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Other SE sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On some sites, you must register in order to post a question or answer. For instance, on Stack Overflow, this adds a nice barrier to entry that helps to prevent a lot of low quality posts.

On other sites, you can simply post with an unregistered account and then link those questions and answers to your account once you've taken the plunge and created one. However, there are some pitfalls with this approach. If a person posts questions and answers and then clears his or her browser cookies prior to registration or sign-in, then the reference to that unregistered account is lost. We oftentimes encounter users who lock themselves out of the ability to edit and comment on their own posts, simply because they were forced to create an unregistered account.

In short, I recommend signing in or registering prior to posting, simply to prevent losing access to your contributions.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/requiring-registration-to-ask-questions-did-it-made-a-difference

Comment: Thanks @gnat. I was thinking about that post while writing this up.